# How to print existing pdf file on specific printer with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm working on a c# project that needs to print some pdf files saved on my computer, but I need send it to printer which is specified by the user in the system, so I don't want to open the system printers modal. I've searched a lot and didn't find how to do this with iTextSharp (version 5.5.13). Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you already have some code that you tried? Could you share your attempts

Comment: Itext does not contain code for rendering pdfs.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was guessing.